# Git- Tracking remote branches

Tags: git, branch

I am a Mercurial user, and I am confused about the behaviour of remote branches. I have a remote branch `origin/dev`, and I want to replicate it on a local branche `dev`. What I would like is that:

- whenever I `git pull`, changes to `origin/dev` are merged into `dev`
- whenever I `git push`, changes to `dev` are merged into `origin/dev`

So I created a tracking branch with

```
git branch --track dev origin/dev
```

which, to the best of my knowledge, should do exactly what I need.

Still, I was working on a feature branch and issued a `git pull`. When I later issued `git checkout dev` I received the puzzling message

> Your branch is behind 'origin/master_dev' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.

So it seems that my local branch was not updated after all. Is there a way to have the branch updated to the remote one whenever I pull and I am not currently in that branch? If not, am I correct that `git merge` (without any arguments) on branch dev is enough to restore the situation?

Comment: Related: [How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/520650/456814).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `git pull` fetches updates from all remote branches (i.e, updates all the remote tracking branches). But merges only the current branch. This is a default behavior of `git pull` when no argument passed.

As you were on a diff branch when you `git pull`, it just updated the remote tracking branch for `dev`. Now `git merge` would be enough to update your local branch `dev`.

Comment: As a side note, [fetch and merge, don't pull](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/).

Comment: Acutally I just tried to simply merge and the result is `fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.` even if the branch was created as tracking

Comment: OK. To get it work, you can do this `git merge remote_name/branch_name`. In your case, `git merge origin/master_dev`.

Comment: Even though the branch is created as tracking, you need to set `merge.defaultToUpstream` as true. It tells GIT to merge with tracking branch when no arguments passed. So either do `git config merge.defaultToUpstream true` and `git merge` OR `git merge remote/branch`