# "No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set"

Tags: git

As a new git user, who is an expert with SVN and CVS, I am struggling to get the most basic of git functions to work.

I'm using a shared repo at assembla.com

I created a local clone, and added a file:

```
$ git clone repository-url
$ echo "hello" > ha.txt
$ git add -A
$ git commit -a -m "haha"
$ git push
```

NOTE: at this point I got "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing" error.
After some hours googling, I found the solution was to type this

```
$ git push origin master
```

Then I went onto another computer, modified the file, and commit-ed it (surprisingly, I didn't need to do the git push origin magic).
Then I back to the main computer, modified it again, so I could see how merge works.

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge
```

Now I get the error:

> **fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.**

Looking at the man page for "git merge", you have to specify something like this:

```
$ git merge [< commit >..]
```

The problem is, I cant find out what `< commit >` means, and what it should be.  E.g. should it be a file, a repo, a message, a version?

I have not created a branch - I'm just working on the "head" or master as I think git calls it

Unfortunately, google is not much help on this one.  The man pages seem to expect you to know what a `< refspec >`, `< commit >` and `origin` are.

Any help on this noob problem appreciated.

Comment: Note: soon, `git config merge.defaultToUpstream true` won't be needed anymore by default for tracking branches: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716957/6309)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Usually you do not invoke `git merge` without arguments (at least I don't know anyone who does). If you want that `merge` defaults to the tracking branch, you need to set `merge.defaultToUpstream` to true: `git config merge.defaultToUpstream true`. Your `master` branch has to track `origin/master` in this case: `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master`. This is done automagically if `origin/master` was already present when you cloned.

Personally, I do `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/master` or `git pull` if I have no local commits.

*Edit: As [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716957/366299) mentioned `merge.defaultToUpstream` defaults to `true` since Git 2.0.*

Comment: Good info, much appreciated.  The command: "git branch -u origin/master master" gives error that u is an unknown switch, unfortunatenly.  I tried cloning the repo again, get same merge problem.  its a real hello world example.

Comment: I tried "git merge origin master".  It worked.  Do I have to do this every time?  Are origin and master short cuts for the local and remote repo URLs?

Comment: Seems that tracking is not enough. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666286/git-tracking-remote-branches I have never set this flag in two years.

Comment: I dont understand any of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666286/git-tracking-remote-branches but setting git config merge.defaultToUpstream true seems to have fixed the problem for good.

Answer (score 8):

Note: if your `master` branch is already tracking `origin/master` (you can see that with `git branch -avvv`, or [a longer alias](https://serverfault.com/a/556917/783)), then a `git merge` **will not display anymore**:

```
fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.
```

The next Git 2.à.x (Q3 2014) will remove that error message:
see [commit a01f7f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a01f7f2ba0e73ffbee0fa1ec9a5a78f276cc173d) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec):

#### `merge`: enable `defaulttoupstream` by default

> There's no point in this:
>
> ```
> % git merge
> fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.
> ```
>
> We know the most likely scenario is that the user wants to merge the upstream, and if not, he can set `merge.defaultToUpstream` to false.

That means you won't need anymore to do a:

```
git config merge.defaultToUpstream true
```

As noted with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021): Defaults to true.

See [commit 8603c41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8603c419d3b7619b9958541461eb024c767cf212) (07 Jun 2021) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 11fac26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/11fac260fe6192cfeb877cf560531e50e1ea2025), 08 Jul 2021)</sup>
<sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Read [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book), it's a very good way to get to know Git.

It will tell you that your `merge`, done with no branch created and with no branch set as merge source, makes no sense.

It will also tell you the difference between `git fetch` and `git pull` which is important.

Fetching changes does not move your branch, but pulling does.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is a much needed settings after the initial git setup. 
Set the default branch mapping as a global option,

`git config --global merge.defaultToUpstream true`