# ZSH plugin to autosuggest text based on previous output

Tags: git, automation, console, zsh, oh-my-zsh

```
(p) ➜  p git:(feature/62-api-custom-image-categories) git checkout develop                               
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
(p) ➜  p git:(develop) git merge feature/62-api-custom-image-categories
```

Is there a solution in ZSH to autosuggest text as you type from previous console output? For example I have a text **feature/62-api-custom-image-categories** and I'd like to autosuggest the name of the branch as I type git merge fe...

Answer (score 0):

```
*[728-reboot-62166][~/w/git/qradar]$ gm
fatal: No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set.
```

["No commit specified and merge.defaultToUpstream not set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223561/no-commit-specified-and-merge-defaulttoupstream-not-set)

```
*[728-reboot-62166][~/w/git/qradar]$ git config merge.defaultToUpstream true
*[728-reboot-62166][~/w/git/qradar]$ gm                                     
Already up-to-date.
```

It seems git can automate part of this by keeping your tracking branch set and the config var set as above.